# jQuery Drag/Drop <li> element styling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list that I want to be drag and droppable to another list with jQuery. The drag drop works fine but I'm running into a problem because I need to display two different bits of information from a database on the same "li" item, but with different styling.

I'd like to be able to add a "track length" to each list item below but I need the track length text to have a different background and text color, but still be part of the same "li" so that the entire thing is draggable. Is there a neat and tidy way to do this with basic htm/css?

```
<ul class="songs">
<li class="song_title">Title 1</li>
<li class="song_title">Title 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can add any markup you want inside an `<li>`.. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Something like this?: <li class="song_title"><span class="time">1:55</span>Title 1</li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a jquery question but you should be able to maintain draggability with the following html structure and get the styling needed for both data pieces.

```
<ul class="songs">
    <li class="song_title">
        <span class="title">Title 1</span>
        <span class="track_length">Some Length</span>
    </li>
    <li class="song_title">
        <span class="title">Title 2</span>
        <span class="track_length">Some Length</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems like the way to do it. Thanks to you and all the guys on here answering the simple questions!